# how to supervisor a new GenServer on Erlang VM do hot upgrade?

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, hot-reload

I'm exploring Elixir language, also deep into Erlang environment recently.

I want to know how to use hot upgrade in this situation:
Usually we deploy a application begin with a root supervisor. After it's running for a few weeks, I want add a new GenServer to the root supervisor.

Could the GenServer be auto start up after deploy a hot upgrade?
Do I need to shutdown and start up the Erlang VM if I'm adding a new GenServer?

Comment: Just kill the supervisor from within it’s [`GenServer.code_change/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#c:code_change/3) callback.

Comment: Hi, sorry for replay so late. Could you give a example about how to properly kill the supervisor and the definition of  `GenServer.code_change/3`?

Comment: @LoranceChen some psuedo code illustrating what you are trying to do might help the answerers provide better answers.